# How can I change the default history and log files paths in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin

Do I need a plugin to change these locations?
I use it with Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the location of your settings and logs, set the environment variable PURPLEHOME.  This is documented [here](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#Wherearemysettingsanddataincludinglogssaved).  Your logs will be in a subdirectory called logs.